# Is there an idiom for Chip on the Shoulder in German?

Tags: idiom

I am trying to explain what a chip on the shoulder means to a German friend and I get back stares of incredulity.

In this context:

> The problem stems from their ancestery. Being conquered by the Romans
> and subsequently made civilized by their conquerors, whereas
> previously they had been barbarians. they felt that they now should do
> the same to other peoples. So they took it upon themselves to start
> colonies in the late 19th century.
>
> Unfortunately for them and
> fortunately for the colonies this didn't quite work out. New Guinea
> would have been hundreds of times worse than what the Belgians did in
> the congo should they have succeeded. This failure, however, left the
> kraut nation, with a huge chip on their shoulder. You average Hun,
> perhaps called Fritz now had this urge to attack with whatever means
> possible anyone who pointed out any of their shortcomings. And do they
> have many shortcomings. Apart from not being able to accept any other
> cultures, they feel an urge to point any small thing out that doesn't
> conform to their sense of normality.

How would you say that someone or a group of peoples has a chip on their shoulder?

Comment: 1. Do not link to sites that contain content that is relevant for understanding the question. Maybe in 10 or 20 years the linked site will no longer exist while German.stackexchange still is online. In this case nobody will understand your question. Instead copy the necessary content into your question. 2. The text on the other site doesn't help to understand what "chip on a shoulder" means. Please describe it in your question.

Comment: I cannot even infer a very secific meaning from that context. "einen Komplex haben"? "eine Bürde tragen"? "einen wunden Punkt haben"?

Comment: You have to explain, what the idiom means, either by describing it, or by using an equivalent idiom. Maybe a few know how to translate it - I don't, and I guess the majority here doesn't. Even DeepL seems to fail. It either suggests "Chip auf der Schulter", ohne dass man ahnen kann, ob Kartoffelchip, IC oder Pokerchip gemeint ist - ob es den Kopf darstellen sollen oder Schulterabzeichen, die man auf Uniformen findet und die den Rang symbolisieren. Wertlos, wie die Alternative sinnlos, die es mit "Stein im Brett" versuchte - in der Tat eine Redewendung, die besagt, dass man Vertrauen genießt.

Comment: I added your quote, but don't know where it originates. Please add the citation source, if you like, to keep it. From my perspective, it isn't of much help, to understand the idiom. It only rules out some ideas, one might have.

Answer (score 1):

Some information about this idiom can be found in the [urban dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=with%20a%20huge%20chip%20on%20their%20shoulder), especially [here](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Chip+on+his+Shoulder):

> **Chip on his Shoulder**
> This has gotten lost in all the false meanings. A chip on his shoulder comes from the days when there was a formal declaration for a fight, punch-up etc. When a person disagreed strongly with someone over a personal belief, they would place a chip of wood on their shoulder and dare the other to knock it off. Once the other person did this signaled the beginning of the fight and thus punches were thrown. Examples of this can be seen in old British movies circa 1930-1950's.

> We use this idiom to say that someone has a deeply held feeling or conviction about something (whether it annoys them or that they won't listen to any other opinion about it) and thus if you disagree then they will vehemently challenge you.
> He has a real chip on his shoulder about his size, I had a chip on my shoulder about immigrants until I moved to another country.

Also look at [this](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=chip+on+my+shoulder):

> **chip on my shoulder**
> This idiom simply means to harbour a grudge. It comes from the nineteenth century US practise of spoiling for a fight by carrying a chip of wood on one's shoulder, daring others to knock it off.

Possible German translations seem to be "eine tiefe Überzeugung haben" and "Groll hegen", although there are certainly other nuances.

But to be honest, I do not understand why you cannot explain this to your German friend. There is no reason to use a German idiom as an translation.